# Is there any way to make fancybox toggle size button, open the full image in a new window?

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I am using the latest fancybox with the buttons helper; is there any way I can make the toggle size button to launch the image alone in a new window rather than showing the full image in fancybox?

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how the toggle size button appears on the page but a simple jQ solution could be something similar to the below code.

```
$('.sizeButton').on('click',function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   activeImgURL = $('.fancybox-inner img').attr('src');
   window.open(activeImgURL);
});
```

Just an idea.... **EDIT** [here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wCQqg/1/) to go with it to.

**EDIT 2-----------------------------**

Ok i see the issue, as the element doesn't exist when the page is first loaded you have to bind the handler to the class for any elements that have not yet been created.

Please see this [edited version of your zip](http://goo.gl/3OfD7).

All I have added is the below code to line 125+.

```
$('body').on('click','.btnToggle' ,function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   activeImgURL = $('.fancybox-inner img').attr('src');
   window.open(activeImgURL);
});
```

Comment: This might be perfect, but how can I make the button only show in the modal window and not the page body?

Comment: Sorry I only added the `.sizeButton` as an example, you would set the current button being created as the trigger.

Comment: Oh is see, I am still a bit confused, would you be able to help?

Comment: all I see is: 
      if (obj.canShrink) {
          toggle.addClass('btnToggleOn');

      } else if (!obj.canExpand) {
         toggle.addClass('btnDisabled');
      }

Do I just replace this with your code?

Comment: Sure, fire any questions.

Comment: Is there an actual button created? If so what is the ID or Class of it?

Comment: There is the toggle button and it is .btnToggle

Comment: ok you should be able to replace `.sizeButton` with `.btnToggle` in the above code and that should hopefully work similar to the fiddle I provided

Comment: I have packaged this for you, is there anyway you could download it and see how to add the button? I am really confused and I tried your suggestion, didnt help - http://sdrv.ms/X3GXX4 - If you download, its under /demo/index.html, scroll down to "button helper"

Comment: Yeah thats fine though im off to sleep now but will look at it first thing.

Comment: YOU ARE MY HERO, thank you very very much :)

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question, clicking the *toggle size button helper* should open the current image in a new browser window/tab, is that correct?

If so, first consider the fancybox toggle size button helper html structure :

```
<a href="javascript:;" title="Toggle size" class="btnToggle"></a>
```

the selector `.btnToggle` is bound within the fancybox script to a function that toggles the size of the current image and it could be very hacky to change that behavior (unbind/destroy the function and assign a new one, etc.)

What I would do is

1). Clone the toggle button helper with another class (I will call it `.btnToggleClone`) and set its css properties exactly the same as the original `.btnToggle` so it can use the same image sprite (./helpers/fancybox_buttons.png)  :

```
#fancybox-buttons a.btnToggleClone {
    background-position: 3px -60px;
    border-left: 1px solid #111111;
    border-right: 1px solid #3E3E3E;
    width: 35px;
}
```

2). Bind a `click` event to the new class to open the current image (`el`) in a new window :

```
$("body").on("click", ".btnToggleClone", function () {
    window.open(el);
});
```

**Notice** that I am using `.on()` in its delegated form so my class will be bound to any current or future DOM element (button helpers are dynamically appended to the DOM when fancybox is opened.)

The parameter `el` (element) will be passed by a fancybox callback (see below)

3). Place my new *class* into the fancybox buttons helpers template using the API option `tpl` like :

```
helpers: {
    buttons: {
        // replace the class "btnToggle" by "btnToggleClone" 
        tpl: '<div id="fancybox-buttons"><ul><li><a class="btnPrev" title="Previous" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnPlay" title="Start slideshow" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnNext" title="Next" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnToggleClone" title="Toggle size" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnClose" title="Close" href="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.close();"></a></li></ul></div>'
    }
}
```

4). Pass the parameter `el` within the fancybox `afterShow` callback like :

```
afterShow: function () {
    el = $(this.element).attr("href");
}
```

where `$(this.element).attr("href")` is the targeted image URL.

Altogether ?

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    closeBtn: false,
    helpers: {
        buttons: {
            // replace class "btnToggle" by "btnToggleClone" 
            tpl: '<div id="fancybox-buttons"><ul><li><a class="btnPrev" title="Previous" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnPlay" title="Start slideshow" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnNext" title="Next" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnToggleClone" title="Toggle size" href="javascript:;"></a></li><li><a class="btnClose" title="Close" href="javascript:jQuery.fancybox.close();"></a></li></ul></div>'
        }
    },
    afterShow: function () {
        el = $(this.element).attr("href");
    }
});
```

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mcgrE/)**

**NOTE** : `.on()` requires jQuery v1.7+

Comment: JFK, This is great, your method and vletech method both worked for me, I actually mixed both to get the results I personally wanted, this answer is also correct but since vletech was helping me since yesterday, I picked his :(

Comment: @unknownsolo : yep, I saw that @vletech edited his answer after mine to bind the action of the `.btnToggle` ... so my answer got his one accepted, such is life. Glad you solved your issue though.